# Is it a good idea to use zlogin's "safe" login mode to shutdown a zone?

Tags: solaris-zones

This question refers to Solaris 10, which does not have a `zoneadm` option to cleanly shutdown a non-global zone.

We have sometimes problems to shutdown non-global zones using `zlogin init 5`. While reading the man-page of `zlogin` I stumbled upon the "safe" login mode option `-s`. The man-page sounds as if the option might have some unpleasant side effect.

> This mode should only be used to recover a damaged zone when other
>   forms of login have become impossible.

But the man-page does not explain it any further. This leads to my question: is it a good idea to always use the `-s` option when trying to shutdown a non-global zone using `zlogin`?